# Iterate IEnumerable selected from IGroupedObservable in RX

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive, tpl-dataflow

I have an `IObservable<T>` sequence where `T` is a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` which I group using `GroupBy` from `System.Reactive.Linq`.

I would like to perform an aggregation operation on each of the `IGroupedObservable<TKey, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` but that aggregation is defined as an `Func<IEnumerable<TValue>, TValue>`.

For example, here I want to count the number of times each distinct word appears and print that to the console:

```
Func<IEnumerable<int>, int> aggregate = x => x.Count();

using (new[] { "one", "fish", "two", "fish" }
    .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(x, 1))
    .ToObservable()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
    .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<int>>(
                x.Key,
                x.Select(y => y.Value).ToEnumerable()))
    //.SubscribeOn(Scheduler.Default)
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Key} [{aggregate(x.Value)}]")))
{
}
```

I expect output similar to this (order is unimportant):

```
one [1]
fish [2]
two [1]
```

But instead it either blocks (probably a deadlock) or gives no output at all (when I uncomment the `SubscribeOn` clause of the LINQ statement).

I have tried to reduce the above code from the actual usage scenario, which attempts to link two TPL Dataflow blocks but encounter similar behaviour:

```
Func<IEnumerable<int>, int> aggregate = x => x.Sum();

var sourceBlock = new TransformBlock<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>>(x => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(x, 1));
var targetBlock = new ActionBlock<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<int>>>(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Key} [{aggregate(x.Value)}]"));
using (sourceBlock.AsObservable()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
    .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<int>>(x.Key, x.Select(y => y.Value).ToEnumerable()))
    .Subscribe(targetBlock.AsObserver()))
{
    foreach (var kvp in new[] { "one", "fish", "two", "fish" })
    {
        sourceBlock.Post(kvp);
    }
    sourceBlock.Complete();
    targetBlock.Completion.Wait();
}
```

I am aware that there are framework provided `Sum` and `Count` methods that operate on `IObservable<T>` but I am constrained to `IEnumerable<T>` aggregation functions.

Have I misunderstood `ToEnumerable` and what can I do to fix it?

**EDIT:**
The constraint of `IEnumerable<T>` is introduced by the *target* of the two dataflow blocks I am trying to link, whose signature is not mine to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GroupBy` works like this: when new element arrives, it extracts a key and sees if that key has already been observed before. If not - it creates new group (new observable) and pushes key and that observable to you. Key point is - when you subscribe to `GroupBy` and item is pushed to your subscription - sequence is *not* yet grouped. What is pushed is group key and another observable (`IGroupedObservable`) to which elements in this group will be pushed.

What you are doing in your code is essentially subscribing to `GroupBy` and then blocking inside `GroupBy` subscription trying to enumerate `IGroupingObservable`. But you cannot enumerate it at this point, because grouping is not complete. For it to be complete - `GroupBy` should process whole sequence, but it cannot, because it's blocked waiting for your subscription handler to complete. And your subscription handler waits for `GroupBy` to complete (blocked trying enumerate not yet ready sequence). Hence you have a deadlock.

If you try to introduce `ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)` to run your subscribe handler on thread pool threads - it will not help. It will remove deadlock, but will introduce race condition instead and you will be losing items, because you only subscribe to individual group when starting to enumerate result of `ToEnumerable`. At this point it might be too late and some and some items were already pushed to individual group observable *before* you subscribed to it (by starting to enumerate). Those items are not replayed and so are lost.

What will help it to indeed use `Count()` provided for `IObservable`, but for some reason you said you cannot do that.

In your case with dataflow blocks, you can try something like this:

```
sourceBlock.AsObservable()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
    .Select(x => {
        var res = new { x.Key, Value = x.Select(y => y.Value).Replay() };
        // subscribe right here
        // Replay will ensure that no items are missed
        res.Value.Connect();
        return res;
    })                
    // observe on thread pool threads to not deadlock if necessary
    // in the example with datablock in your question - it is not
    //.ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
    // now no deadlock and no missing items
    .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<int>>(x.Key, x.Value.ToEnumerable()))
    .Subscribe(targetBlock.AsObserver())
```

Comment: if you look at the dataflow example, you'll see the block signature takes `IEnumerable<int>` as part of each input and the block applies an aggregation function (that's not necessarily `Count` or `Sum`: these were toy examples for my MVCE) to it. Hopefully my edit makes this more clear.

Comment: @Jono I've updated answer with one option that came to mind.

Comment: thank you for your help. I wish we could highlight parts of an answer because it started to make sense when you said "you only subscribe ... when starting to enumerate". I tried a quick `Replay` of my own but I missed out `Connect` so it still had a race condition. Your answer fixes that.